# How to concat string + i?

Tags: string, matlab, loops, for-loop, octave

```
for i=1:N
   f(i) = 'f'+i;
end
```

gives an error in MatLab. What's the correct syntax to initialize an array with N strings of the pattern fi?

It seems like even this is not working:

```
for i=1:4
  f(i) = 'f';
end
```

Comment: Exactly what do you want the array `f` to look like? A single string with all of the individual `fi` strings concatenated together? A character array with one string per row? A cell array ?

Comment: For recent version of MATLB, use strings. For example `"asd" + (1:5)` works then.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can concatenate strings using [`strcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strcat.html).  If you plan on concatenating numbers as strings, you must first use [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html) to convert the numbers to strings.

Also, strings can't be stored in a vector or matrix, so `f` must be defined as a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html), and must be indexed using `{` and `}` (instead of normal round brackets).

```
f = cell(N, 1);
for i=1:N
   f{i} = strcat('f', num2str(i));
end
```

Comment: Something like "f(i) = sprintf('%s%d', f, i);" would work as well.

Comment: my issue was the lacking use of curly brackets to index

Comment: `['f', num2str(i)]` is a bit shorter.

Answer (score 24):

### For versions prior to R2014a...

One easy non-loop approach would be to use [`genvarname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html) to create a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of strings:

```
>> N = 5;
>> f = genvarname(repmat({'f'}, 1, N), 'f')

f = 

    'f1'    'f2'    'f3'    'f4'    'f5'
```

### For newer versions...

The function `genvarname` has been deprecated, so [`matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.lang.makeuniquestrings.html) can be used instead in the following way to get the same output:

```
>> N = 5;
>> f = strrep(matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings(repmat({'f'}, 1, N), 'f'), '_', '')

 f =
   1×5 cell array

     'f1'    'f2'    'f3'    'f4'    'f5'
```

Comment: This is actually a great solution.  I wasn't aware of `genvarname`.

Comment: FYI: `genvarname` is deprecated.

Answer (score 10):

Let me add another solution:

```
>> N = 5;
>> f = cellstr(num2str((1:N)', 'f%d'))
f = 
    'f1'
    'f2'
    'f3'
    'f4'
    'f5'
```

If `N` is more than two digits long (`>= 10`), you will start getting extra spaces. Add a call to `strtrim(f)` to get rid of them.

---

As a bonus, there is an undocumented built-in function `sprintfc` which nicely returns a cell arrays of strings:

```
>> N = 10;
>> f = sprintfc('f%d', 1:N)
f = 
    'f1'    'f2'    'f3'    'f4'    'f5'    'f6'    'f7'    'f8'    'f9'    'f10'
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `sprintf` was already proposed by ldueck in a comment, but I think this is worth being an answer:

```
f(i) = sprintf('f%d', i);
```

This is in my opinion the most readable solution and also gives some nice flexibility (i.e. when you want to round a float value, use something like `%.2f`).

Answer (score 2):

according to [this](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/matlab/control.html#for) it looks like you have to set "N" before trying to use it and it looks like it needs to be an int not string? Don't know much bout MatLab but just what i gathered from that site..hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
for i = 1:4
    result = strcat('f',int2str(i));
end
```

If you use this for naming several files that your code generates, you are able to concatenate more parts to the name. For example, with the extension at the end and address at the beginning:

```
filename = strcat('c:\...\name',int2str(i),'.png');
```